# undefined is not an object (evaluating 'window.navigator.userAgent.match')

Tags: react-native, socket.io, netty-socketio

I'm using [netty-socketio](https://github.com/mrniko/netty-socketio)
for my backend socket.io solution. Which requires socket.io-client to be 1.0+. If I use this version of socket client I'm getting this issue.

- socket io server used is 1.3.1
- Protocol it supports 1.0

In RN the socket client version is 1.0.1

Answer (score 2):

The `window` object represents the browser's window. You are working in `native` environment, so there is no browser. As a result there is no `window` object.